# String printing incorrectly in table view after JSON parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I one of my apps, i parse some data from local host and print it in a table view. To get the data, the user first logs in using an alert view. The user id entered is then used to fetch the data which i parse using JSON.

There is definitely a very simple solution to this question but I can't seem to be able to fix it. The problem is that when I print the data the string comes in this format:

(   "string" )

But I want it so that it just says : string

in the table view. Here is my parsing method:

```
 - (void)updateMyBooks
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Fetch data on a background thread:

    NSString *authFormatString =
    @"http://localhost:8888/Jineel_lib/bookBorrowed.php?uid=%@";

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",UserID];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:authFormatString, string];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSLog(@"uel is %@", url);

    NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    response1 = [contents JSONValue];

    if (contents) {

        // ... Parse JSON response and add objects to newBooksBorrowed ...
        BookName = [[NSString alloc]init];
        DateBorrowed = [[NSString alloc]init];
        BookID = [[NSString alloc]init];
        BookExtended = [[NSString alloc]init];
        BookReturned = [[NSString alloc]init];

        BookName = [response1 valueForKey:@"BookName"];
        BookID = [response1 valueForKey:@"BookID"];
        DateBorrowed = [response1 valueForKey:@"DateBorrowed"];
        BookExtended = [response1 valueForKey:@"Extended"];
        BookReturned = [response1 valueForKey:@"Returned"];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update data source array and reload table view.
            [BooksBorrowed addObject:BookName];
            NSLog(@"bookBorrowed array = %@",BooksBorrowed);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
});
}
```

This is how I print it in the table view:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSLog(@"string is %@",string);
cell.textLabel.text = string;
```

When I use log during the parsing process, it comes out as (   "string" ) so the problem is somewhere in the parsing, at least thats what I think.

Comment: And where's the question about Xcode?

Comment: I am doing it in xocde in apple ios coding language, hence the xcode tag

Comment: how does the JSON look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

returns something like "( string )" then the most probably reason is that

```
[BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

is not a *string*, but an *array* containing a string. In that case,

```
NSString *string = [[BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
```

should be the solution.

Comment: thanks for the solution, fixed about three of my problems :) If you check some of my other questions you will realise that I have been having problems surrounding this one issue which you fixed so everything is now resolved the way it should be rather than otherwise suggested... So thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];


    NSLog(@"string is %@",string);
    cell.textLabel.text = string;
```

**EDIT:**

Above code is used if it's showing text in that format in your label.

If you see that in `NSlog` then it's `NSString` inside `NSArray`.
You need to fetch that string first from array and then display,  use code line suggested by @Martin R for that.

```
NSString *string = [[BooksBorrowed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: yay! Thank you so much, I should have thought of that >.<

Comment: That is fixing the symptoms but hardly a solution for the problem.

Comment: -1. So either this code is incorrect or correct. Either OP is brave or down voter.

Comment: This code will remove *all* parentheses, for example `( "Title (Part 1)" )` is transformed to `Title Part 1`.